# Logic Gate using Transistor and Diode not working on Proteus

Tags: logic-gates, proteus, nand

Logic Gate using Transistor and Diode not working on Proteus, just show ON light different on MultiSims is always work as the Logic Gate's Schematic. 
For example Logic NOT :
[image: PROTEUS just Light "ON" never show "OFF"]
PROTEUS just Light "ON" never show "OFF" at "NOT Logic Gate". 
Please help me What the best schematic for Logic Gates only use Transistor and Diode without IC 7400 etc can work as good as Multisim.

Comment: What are R4 and D3 supposed to do?  For that fact why is D1 in there?

Comment: To continue: why is R3 common to both Q1 and Q2? why is the LED on the emitter side, (instead of on the collector side). *Where did you find this circuit??*

Comment: I'm trying discard D1, D4, R4 but still show Light "ON" never "OFF". What's your schematic NOT in PROTEUS ? BCoz I tried that circuit work on Multisim.

Comment: You show no ground in your circuit. What is the reference for the external input connected to R1?

Answer (score 1):

This is a NOT gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWbRQm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When In is 0V, Out is 5V.

When In is 5V, Out is 0V.

---

To make an LED show the output state, you will need an LED driver.

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frOjcR.png)</sup>

When LogicIn is 0V then the LED is off.

When LogicIn is 5V then the LED will light.

---

Now, combine the two.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff3tks.png)</sup>

When In is 0V, then the LED lights.

When In is 5V, then the LED will go out.

Answer (score 0):

finally I change my circuit to be work in PROTEUS. I try there's no errors and exact with expectation in PROTEUS.
[image]
Before it (PROTEUS( I try in MultiSim that's work. This is my circuit in MultiSim :
[image]